# How to write a javascript funcion to check that my text box is containg special character or not?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I want to check that my text box is containing special character or not, using java script.
for this i am using following code

```
function CheckUserId() {
    var txt = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value;
    var regexp = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/";
    if (regexp.match(txt)) {
        alert("No special character ");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Special character");
        return false;
    }
    }
```

I am calling this java script function on textbox onblur. TextBox code is following

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onblur="CheckUserId()" ></asp:TextBox>
```

but it is showing always alert message  "special character" .Whats wrong with my code?
Please help me

Comment: Please have a look at this document http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/234476/Javascript-to-Check-if-field-has-special-character

Answer (score 5):

You have the string and the pattern the wrong way round on your if statement. The syntax for a javascript match is `string.match(regexp)`. Try instead:

```
if (txt.match(regexp))
```

Comment: I changed according to your suggestion then also same output. Is my regular expression right?

Comment: Remove the pattern from the string and it will work. Ie. `var regexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;` Although, do note that the pattern does not allow for spaces. I don't know if that is intentional, but to include them just add a space into the character class.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others pointed, you have made another mistake: `var regexp = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/"` is a string, not RegExp object. [Remove quotes](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) around regular expression or use `var regexp = new RegExp("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/")` syntax.

Here is the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/LJdeE/

```
function CheckUserId() {
    var txt = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value;
    var reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
    if (reg.test(txt)) {
        alert("No special character");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Special character");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is `(text.match(regex))` and **not** `(regex.match(text))`

Answer (score 0):

```
^\s*([0-9a-zA-Z ]+)\s*$
```

try this regex.
i have tried it it is working